# md-tabs inside md-tab-group do not remain fixed while scrolling

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material tabs for this thing. My code is as shown below:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab style="position: fixed;top:0;" label={{category}} *ngFor="let category of itemCategory">
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

and css for that is :

```
.q-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    z-index: 100000000;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    color: white;
    background-color: #42AB9E;
}
```

But somehow, the tabs do not remain fixed while scrolling. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Which AM version are you using?

Comment: @Vega `"2.0.0-beta.11`

Comment: Is it a specific choice? Latest version is a lot ahead

Comment: I integrated it few months back, at that time this was the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Use ::ng-deep.**

> Use the /deep/ shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style
>   down through the child component tree into all the child component
>   views. The /deep/ combinator works to any depth of nested components,
>   and it applies to both the view children and content children of the
>   component. Use /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep only with emulated view
>   encapsulation. Emulated is the default and most commonly used view
>   encapsulation. For more information, see the Controlling view
>   encapsulation section. The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is
>   deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools.
>   As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>>
>   and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader
>   compatibility with the tools.

**CSS**:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header{
      z-index: 999;
      width:100vw;
      position: fixed;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bp2sxg)**

**2. Use ViewEncapsulation**

> ... component CSS styles are encapsulated into the component's view
>   and don't affect the rest of the application. To control how this
>   encapsulation happens on a per component basis, you can set the view
>   encapsulation mode in the component metadata. Choose from the
>   following modes: .... None means that Angular does no view
>   encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping
>   rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This
>   is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the
>   HTML.

None value is what you will need to set material style from your
component.

**Typscript:**

```
  import {ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
  ....
  @Component({
        ....
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
 })
```

**CSS**

```
.mat-tab-header{
      z-index: 999;
      width:100vw;
      position: fixed;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bp2sxg-mbbfn4)

**3. Setting styles in style.css**

This time you have to 'force' styles with !important.

style.css

```
.mat-tab-header{
      z-index: 999;
      width:100vw;
      position: fixed  !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bp2sxg-kdg4vi)